# How to get all products that aren't in a specific category in Magento?

Tags: product, collection, catalog

I'm having issue trying to get all the products that aren't in a specific category. Here's a code that works fine until I added the 'join-nin' query.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        'status',
                        ['eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED])
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', [ 'in' =>[ 2, 4 ] ]);
```

Here's my 'join-nin'

```
$collection = $collection->joinField('category_xxx', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('category_xxx', ['nin'=>24])
```

Now I know that currently, it would give me duplicate products (result) for some reason so I have to group the result by 'e.entity_id'

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Then when I looped through the collection and print/echo their Ids, I see the product which I specifically assigned to that category (24).

TLDR:
I need to query all products with using 'in' and 'nin' for any categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but it looks like it's working for me. I'll try and come up with a better filter method, but for now try this:

Join the field, specifying the category ID you **don't want** as one of the left join conditions. This way, you can highlight within the query which products do exist in that category, then filter against that:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status',
        ['eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED]
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['in' => [2, 4]])
    ->joinField(
        'category_we_dont_want',
        'catalog/category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id = entity_id',
        ['category_id' => 24],
        'left'
    );
```

Then, filter by products that didn't meet that join condition. In a left join, if the condition `category_id => 24` isn't met the field value will just be null:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('at_category_we_dont_want.category_id IS NULL');
```

This should give you products in your collection that don't exist in category 24.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping.
Your new updated code, the `category_filter` seems not to work but what you had previously does and I can query for multiple `nin`. With your new code, I get an error "Call to a member function getBackend()".

Comment: Fair call, here's me trying to do it the "right" way. I'll revert that edit.

Comment: `$collection->getSelect()->where("at_category_we_dont_want.category_id IS NULL");` Here's the previous working code for me.